# Looking for example of C# WinForms app showing output from a batch file

Tags: c#, batch-file

I am looking for a c# example project of a WinForms app which redirects the output from a batch file running in background to any kind of WinForms control.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you're going to find a direct example, but it's not overly difficult. I don't have time to write all the code for you, but I can give you the code from MSDN:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = 
    new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\MyBatchFile.bat" );
myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
myProcess.Start();

StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;

// Read the standard output of the spawned process.
string myString = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

myProcess.Close();

// Now you have the output of the batch file in myString
```

Comment: I would suggest `myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();`, but a solid +1. ;)

Comment: @Lance May - I meant to make that change before posting. That was what MSDN originally used. I made the update.

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451228/how-to-send-input-to-the-console-as-if-the-user-is-typing/451986#451986) here.

It will show you how to redirect the output to an event.  You can then take the output and put it into your win control.