# Win32 equivalent of .net SendKeys

Tags: c++, winapi, sendkeys

I am designing a system that reads a gesture from Kinect and make some actions. I am trying to include the system to be able to send HotKey to an application. My system is writing in c++ but the UI is in C++.net. I have been able to use SendKeys from the UI part and it does work.

Is there a Win32 equivalent so I can use it in my system?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to communicate between your own C++ and C# code, or are you trying to send a hotkey to another separate application? (Or, asking another way, does the gesture control your own UI, or do you want to control other applications?)

Comment: I am trying to send the hotkey to others applications like Windows Media Player, Adobe Reader or PowerPoint.

Comment: SendInput is probably the way to go then. Note that, just like SendKeys, the input ends up going to whatever app currently has focus, you don't really send input "to an application", you really send input to the system, and the system routes it appropriately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In WIN32, SendKeys is called SendInput:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx

It can also simulate mouse movements, etc.

Comment: +1 - Minor note - SendInput isn't a *direct equivalent* for SendKeys. SendKeys is really a helper wrapper around SendInput that does much of the work for you. With SendInput, you have to fill out a set of structs for every key press and release rather than just passing a simple string. Still the right API to use here.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple applications, on Vista and higher, UAC integrity levels may prevent applications from sending/receiving Windows messages this way. You may need to call [ChangeWindowMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions to enable message-reception in *higher* elevated process.

Comment: These affect only windows messages (WM_* and the like) sent via SendMessage and/or PostMessage, not input sent via SendInput. (Input is affected by integrity levels, but these APIs don't affect how it is filtered.)

Comment: You are probably wrong: "This function is subject to UIPI. Applications are permitted to inject input only into applications that are at an equal or lesser integrity level."

Comment: That's what I meant by "Input is affected by integrity levels, but these APIs don't affect how it is filtered". Like I said, these APIs don't affect how SendInput works. In any case, these APIs are only of use within the target app, which can effectively use them to "lower the shields", and allow in WM_ messages that would otherwise be filtered out by UIPI  - they are of no use at all in the app that is calling SendInput in the first place. If you want to be able to SendInput to a higher IL app, you need to run elevated.

Comment: Not true, Windows Explorer's custom message "TaskbarCreated" is send from lower IL process (explorer.exe), and can be intercepted by higher IL process. 

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsuidevelopment/thread/f4370108-9cf9-4353-a086-a6f5112947ce

Comment: I think you're mixing up input/SendInput vs messages/SendMessage. The qu here is about SendInput, which sends low-level keyup/keydown (or mouse move) input to the currently active thread. Windows filters those based on IL level, and doesn't take the message filter into account. USER32 will eventually translate that low-level input those into key-related window messages, but by that stage it's already passed the UIPI filters. On the other hand, *messages* that a low-IL app sends to a higher-IL app using SendMessage or PostMessage (and that includes "TaskbarCreated") are filtered by those APIs.

Answer (score -1):

The native equivalent is `keybd_event`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As per MSDN: "Note: This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead."